# ASP.NET MVC w/ EF Code first - one controller and 50 'the same' models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, ef-code-first

I have like 50 of this 'Type models' (as i call them), and they look like this:

```
public class BookType{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class CarType{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class PersonType{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

So all this models are the same accept for the class name, all these models are going to have relationships with other models.

I need to design a functionality to provide CRUD operations. I want to do this all in one controller and 1 view for edit, 1 for create, and 1 for delete.

We use EF Code first for data access. So i have to do something like:

```
PersonType tp = new PersonType()
DbContext.PersonTypes.Add(pt)
```

But then, PersonTypes could also be of the type BookType. I played a little around with reflection and interfaces, but with no success.

**Isnt there some kind of best practice for this?**

**Anyone have suggestions? or examples?**

Comment: "Value1" and "Value2" is a code smell.  Take a careful look at your object model and see if you can be more explicit about object properties.  Then you'll probably want to implement a table-per-type inheritance scheme (Google it, you'll find plenty).

Comment: are you using value1, value2 as examples ie. there is different data stored per class, or are the actual properties called value1 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to perform the same operations, regardless of whether it's a `BookType`, `CarType`, etc., why not just unify all these under one table and add a `Category` column?

Your entity classes would look like this:

```
public class EditableType {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class Category {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You could create an `enum` if the names of your categories are known in advance (which it sounds like they are).

```
public enum CategoryToken {
    Book,
    Person,
    Car
    //...
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var personTypes = dbContext.EditableTypes
    .Where(et => et.Category == (int)CategoryToken.Person);
var carTypes = dbContext.EditableTypes
    .Where(et => et.Category == (int)CategoryToken.Car);

var pt = new EditableType
{
    CategoryId = (int)CategoryToken.Person,
    Value1 = "Programmer",
    Value2 = "C#"
};
DbContext.EditableTypes.Add(pt)
```

Comment: This model will break if in future they want add other category specific properties.

Comment: @Eranga, true, but the premise of the question was that the design was the same for 50 categories. I have no idea if this is likely to change in the future, but for right now, it seems like a violation of DRY to write 50 classes that are identical except for name.